# iOS simulator issue with SceneKit displays only black shapes

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, simulator, scnnode

I have developed a small dice rolling app using SceneKit. While everything works correctly on device my dice nodes are shown as black shapes in the simulator. This used to work fine before but I stopped working on the app for a year and Xcode updated since. You can find screenshots of the issue below.

I tried using an other version of Xcode (11 beta). I tried deleting everything Xcode and Simulator related and reinstalling. I tried disabling every fancy effect on my dice nodes but nothing seems to have an impact, the issue really seems to come from the simulator rendering.

As anyone ever encountered a similar issue? Any help on how to fix it would be appreciated as I use Fastlane Snapshot to generate new screenshots when I release.

Simulator Screenshot:

[image]

Device Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by trying random stuff: the culprit seems to be my SCNLight node that lights the scene. My light type was set to .spot but if I set it to something else my dice appear correctly in the simulator.